# Distortion in objects that i look perpendicular to, in making my own Ray caster renderer enginer

Tags: javascript, p5.js, raycasting

So im making a p5.js ray cast renderer, and Im facing some strange distortion.
To explain the images, the top half of the draw is the 2d view, and the bottom half is rendered with the code below

[The right wall is completely boinked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojXsS.jpg)

[And here is to show that its not fisheye effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYKQk.jpg)

```
    show3d(bounds){
    push();
    translate(0,3*height/4);
    const widthPerColumn=1;
    var x=0;
    this.rays.forEach(ray => {
        const closePoint=ray.findFirstCollision(bounds);
        if(!closePoint)
        {
            //no hit on this ray
            x+=widthPerColumn;
            return;
        }
        //head angle is in degree, ray angle in radians. multiplied by cos to fix fisheye
        const dist=closePoint.dist(this.position)*cos(radians(this.headAngle)-ray.angle);
        const maxDist=createVector(0,0).dist(createVector(width,height/2));
        var paintColor=map(dist*dist,0,maxDist*maxDist,255,0);
        var columnHeight=map(dist,0,maxDist,height/2,0);
        noStroke();
        fill(paintColor)
        rect(x, -columnHeight/2,widthPerColumn , columnHeight);    
        x+=widthPerColumn;
    });
    pop();

}
```

where bounds is an array of all walls in the scene. Im kinda stumped as I havent found this issue on the other projects where this has been done.

Comment: the left wall looks slightly "boinked" as well.

Comment: It does.so the closer i am to the wall, and the more parallel i look to, the worse it is. Any ideas?

Comment: Just a guess, perhaps you want to use a rectilinear projection, which may demand a different height function. This expression can also be solved by intersecting a ray with a plane (a set of linear equations that has a closed form solution).